# Matching for the Values in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

I have bunch of objects in an array with format as below:

```
[
  {
    "card_details": {
      "cardType": "gift"
    },
    "merchant_details": {
      "merchantName": "Walter Heisenberg1",
      "timeZone": "+05:30",
    }
  },
  {
    "card_details": {
      "cardType": "coupon",
      "cardTitle": "Coupon",
      "messageUser": "Hi",
      "punchCount": null,
      "messageReachPunchLimit": "Get your Freebie!",
      "merchantId": "59c214000e1a7825184cb813",
      "expiryDate": "21 Sep 2019",
      "discountPercent": "15",
      "cardImageUrl": ""
    },
    "merchant_details": {
      "merchantName": "Walter Heisenberg1",
      "timeZone": "+05:30"
    }
  },
  {
    "card_details": {
      "cardType": "punch",
      "cardTitle": "BlueM2",
      "messageUser": "Welcome!",
      "expiryDate": "21 Sep 2019",
      "punchCount": 25,
      "messageReachPunchLimit": "Get your Freebie!",
      "merchantId": "59c214000e1a7825184cb813",
      "cardImageUrl": "http://139.59.179.111/cloopapi/undefined"
    },
    "merchant_details": {
      "merchantName": "Walter Heisenberg1",
      "timeZone": "+05:30"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to filter the objects based on cardType in the card_details object. But I want to search from the array. For example, if I search for ["coupon","gift"], then I should get the all the cards which have the card_details.cardType as coupon or gift. 
I need to be able to do this in Node.js,i.e., Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ES6 `filter` and `includes` functions here:

```
collection.filter(item => ['coupon', 'gift'].includes(item.card_details.cardType))
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this in ES5?